# Facing Arguments exception error on retrieving data from list of a query using c# in a cross platform xamarin project (ios and android)

Tags: c#, android, ios, list, xamarin

Facing Arguments exception error on retrieving data from list of a query using c# in a cross platform xamarin project (ios and android). I am trying to retrieve data from easy tables on azure (cloud). here's my code

```
try
{
    var client = new MobileServiceClient("https://eg.azurewebsites.net");
    IMobileServiceTable<Reg> regTable = client.GetTable<Reg>();
    Reg reg = new Reg();

    string imail = uemail2.Text.ToString();

    // This query to seach email
    var email1 = await regTable
        .Where(Reg => Reg.email.ToString() == imail)
        .Select(email => email.Text.ToString())
        .ToListAsync();

    notice3.Text = email1[0].ToString();
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    notice.Text = "Arguments Error" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + ex.HelpLink + ex.Source;
}
```

**ERROR DETAILS**

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutofRange_IndexException....
>   ...//continued ex.Source = mscorlib

**Thanks in Advance**

My Updated Query:

```
 public async Task<ObservableCollection<Reg>> GetTodoItemsAsync(bool syncItems = false)
     {
var client = new MobileServiceClient("https://eg.azurewebsites.net");
             IMobileServiceTable<Reg> regTable = client.GetTable<Reg>();
             Reg reg = new Reg();

             string imail= uemail2.Text.ToString();

         IEnumerable<Reg> items = await regTable
                     .Where(email=> email.Text.ToString() == imail)
                     .ToEnumerableAsync();

         return new ObservableCollection<Reg>(items);
     }

private async void v_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

var client = new MobileServiceClient("https://eg.azurewebsites.net");
            IMobileServiceTable<Reg> regTable = client.GetTable<Reg>();
            Reg reg = new Reg();

            string imail = uemail2.Text.ToString();

await GetTodoItemsAsync();
            items email3 = new items();



            vnotice2.Text = email3.ToString();
}
```

Comment: are you sure `email1` is not null and has at least one element in it?

Comment: @Jason Yes, you are right. I have Used Count. The output is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `email1` is empty, so it's unable to find first element in the list and cuasing index out of exception.
You should validate the list before accessing any elements of that list.

```
if(email1.Count > 0)
    notice3.Text = email1[0].ToString();
```

Possible reason for getting empty email1, might be the string comparison in where clause, you should ignore the case and compare the strings unless you are sure that both parameters in comparison have same case. Also if you want to fetch only one email then you should use FirstOrDefaultAsync. The modified query will look like below.

```
notice3.Text = await regTable
                .Where(Reg => Reg.email.Equals(imail, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .Select(email => email.Text.ToString()).FirstOrDefaultAsync<string>()
```

Comment: Thanks @Vinit, Is my query right? How can i retrieve table data from an "Easy Table". Do I have to use .Take(1) ? Why email1  is null.

Comment: @Aslam Ranjha - Updated my answer based on your questions.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time. VS is giving error "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IMobileServiceTableQuery<string>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefaultAsync' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefaultAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IMobileServiceTableQuery<string>'" could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" and when i used it with         .ToListAsync(); it throws exception that Equals() isn't supported with Where.

Comment: what Changes I make to make it working.i've find this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/azure but it's giving false output like "PROJECTNAME.CLASSNAME". I need email as output.